# jsTree move child to root from one tree to other

Tags: jquery, jstree, jstree-dnd

I am facing problem in jsTree. I want to move child node to root node and viseversa. Also i can move from first tree child to root of second tree. Please help me .

Please find my below jsfiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/ubo3tjzk/

```
First tree
<div id="tree"></div>

Second tree
<div id="tree2"></div>

var data = [
     { "id" : "root", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root", "state":{"opened":true} },
     { "id" : "cat1", "parent" : "root", "text" : "First Branch", "state":{"opened":true}  },
     { "id" : "cat01", "parent" : "cat1", "text" : "Cat 0.1.0" },
     { "id" : "cat02", "parent" : "cat1", "text" : "Cat 0.1.1" },
     { "id" : "cat03", "parent" : "cat1", "text" : "Cat 0.1.2" }
]

var data2 = [
     { "id" : "cat2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Second Branch", "state": {"opened":true}},
     { "id" : "cat11", "parent" : "cat2", "text" : "Cat 1.1.0" },
     { "id" : "cat12", "parent" : "cat2", "text" : "Cat 1.1.1"  },
     { "id" : "cat13", "parent" : "cat2", "text" : "Cat 1.1.2" }
]

$.jstree.defaults.core = {};

$('#tree')
    .on('changed.jstree', function (event, data) {
          if( data.action == 'select_node'){ 
              $('#tree').find('li').removeClass('disabled_node');
              currentlevel = parseInt( $('#'+data.node.id).attr('aria-level') );
              $('#tree').find('li').each( function() {
                  if($(this).attr('aria-level') > currentlevel) {
                    $(this).addClass('disabled_node');   
                  }
              });

          }
          if( data.action == 'deselect_node'){ 
              $('#tree').find('li').each( function() {
                  if($(this).attr('aria-level') > currentlevel) {
                    $(this).removeClass('disabled_node');   
                  }
              }); 
          }
    })
    .jstree({
    "core" : {
        "data" : data,
        "themes": {
            "url": true,
            "icons": true
        }
    }
 });  


$('#tree2')
    .on('changed.jstree', function (event, data) {
          if( data.action == 'select_node'){ 
              $('#tree').find('li').removeClass('disabled_node');
              currentlevel = parseInt( $('#'+data.node.id).attr('aria-level') );
              $('#tree').find('li').each( function() {
                  if($(this).attr('aria-level') > currentlevel) {
                    $(this).addClass('disabled_node');   
                  }
              });

          }
          if( data.action == 'deselect_node'){ 
              $('#tree').find('li').each( function() {
                  if($(this).attr('aria-level') > currentlevel) {
                    $(this).removeClass('disabled_node');   
                  }
              }); 
          }
    })
    .jstree({
    "core" : {
        "data" : data2,
        "themes": {
            "url": true,
            "icons": true
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/ubo3tjzk/1/ . Is this what you want?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh - Thanks bro. But i dont want to drag and drop the positions with in first tree. Only to second tree i can push. ALso can i achieve delete node option with delete image

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: the example what u shared is perfect. Can we avoid dnd within first tree ? Also can we achive delete node option in jstree if i select and delete the node and should remove from tree

Comment: For 1, not sure though, for 2, https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=delete_node(obj) . I believe both the trees should have `dnd` enabled.

Comment: Thanks bro :) for the link i will explore on 1.

Comment: Let me know if you come up with anything. Or accept an answer.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh - Any idea tree expand by default not works in IE browser. Please help on this

Comment: try with latest version of IE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check demo - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/xuap2uh1/)

You can restrict drop to the first tree with:

```
'check_callback': function(operation, node, node_parent, node_position, more) {
    if (operation === "move_node") {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To delete selected node from the first tree use:

```
var node = $("#tree").jstree('get_selected');
$("#tree").jstree('delete_node', node);
```

To delete a node on click place the above snippet into `select_node.jstree` event.

Check second demo - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/6x2jvq7c/)

Comment: @NikolaErmakov - Can we achieve each node with delete icon. Please help i have added delete option in first tree http://jsfiddle.net/xuap2uh1/2/

Comment: Can you please explain what it is that - `achieve each node with delete icon`.

Comment: can we have node with delete option like on click of delete image node should delete.

Comment: Thank you very much bro. Lastly from Second tree i want to drag and drop to external div to delete from second tree.is this possible

Comment: Yes bro it helped alot.

Comment: One last help needed is i do not want to delete from left tree node when i drag and drop to right

Comment: You can hold `ctrl` button when dragging. Will that do?

Comment: No bro .. Just drag from left to right. and it should not disappear from left tree. Without holding ctrl button

Comment: Then add `"dnd": { "always_copy": true }` to tree settings - http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/ytpz1bpy/

Comment: Awesome bro helped alot

Comment: When i do $('#jstree_demo2').data().jstree , I get extra data in JSON. Can i get clean Json data as we give for tree

Answer (score 0):

This is what I achieved so far -

jsfiddle.net/ubo3tjzk/1